# Jenkins pipeline job keeps on creating pods inside kubernetes cluster

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

Recently I have been trying to setup a pipeline inside jenkins. The aim is to create a pod and perform kubernetes deployment.

**But when i run the pipeline job it keeps on creating pods one after another, it never completes the job -**

[image]

### Here are steps -

1. Setup the kubernetes cluster - successfully
2. Installed jenkins - successfully
3. Connected jenkins to kubernetes cluster - successfully
4. Here is the pipeline script  -

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      //cloud 'kubernetes'
      yaml """
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jhooq-pod-with-pvc
    image: rahulwagh17/kubernetes:jhooq-k8s-springboot
    imagePullPolicy: Always
"""
    }
  }
  stages {
      stage('build') {
          steps {
              echo "Hello World!"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

**Not** - Pods are getting created successfully and kubernetes deployment is also successful but the jenins pipeline never stops.

And my jenkins in connected to kubernetes without any issues.

[image]

Any suggestions or input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: To me this a symptom of your pods not created successfully, check in the logs of you pods if they are effectively created with success.

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis I do not see any issue with the pod creation. PODs are getting created and deleted

Comment: Sorry, but I faced the same issue. Pods are created endlessly. Did you find the reason ? What is going on... Also I should note:`Nov 23, 2022 2:37:57 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: WebSocket connection open
Nov 23, 2022 2:37:57 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because, your Jenkins agent is not connecting to your master.

This you can validate in the node monitoring under Manage Jenkins.
It should be something like below:

[image: Jenkins Agent Provisioning]

Comment: i verified connection it is connected to master. I verified by going into configure cloud-> Test Connection and its say : Connected to Kubernetes 1.19. I have update the question with screenshot

Comment: No, I am not talking about kubernetes cluster connection, that is connected and can be seen, but the slave agent image which you are using, that slave has to connect to master. Image which you are using for jenkins pod agent should be an image of jenkins slave. In that image you can install based on your requirement. https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/slave/

Comment: Also find the below link for jenkins slave dockerfile. https://gist.github.com/Vijaydaswani/97cc3b7224d8fbebc60df26c40a23a69 , You will also need the jenkins-agent binary, let me know if you need. I can share.

Comment: I will give it a try first as soon as i get some time